# MZCommerceInAppBuy.App BuyInfoDataAccessFailure_message

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, ios9, storekit

So I'm testing out an in-app purchase in my app. I've got the code set up properly and everything, but when I do attempt to buy or restore in the sandbox environment, I get this error:

MZCommerceInAppBuy.App BuyInfoDataAccessFailure_message
[Environment: Sandbox]

I've never seen this before, and I am finding only one Google search result from someone else who has. It never was solved. Has anybody seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  The problem was coming because I was adding an in-app purchase to the current live version of my app.  I created a new version of my app and changed it on my target to the update version.

I also downloaded a new development provisioning profile. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but I wanted to add that I created a new one just in case.

When you add in-app purchases to an app, you must create a new app version even for testing.

**Note:**

Just a side note.  I noticed while I received this error I also wan't receiving any in-app purchase products.  You will not receive any products until you create the new version.